# cant encode character in python

Tags: python, character, encode

I've got a character for a blackjack game but python can't encode it. I've looked up a few things but have not found a good solution and need help.
The error:UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2666' in position 5: character maps to undefined
Here's my code:

> ```
> SUITES = ["♥", "♠", "♣", "♦"]
> RANKS = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','X','J','Q','K']
> VALUES = [11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10]
> ```

> ```
> class Card:
>     def __init__(self, suit, rank):
>         self.suit = suit
>         self.rank = rank
>         self.value = VALUES[RANKS.index(rank)]
>
>     def get_str(self):
>         print("{} of {}".format(self.rank, self.suit))
> ```

Comment: This is an issue with how your console is configured, rather than the Python code itself. " I've looked up a few things but have not found a good solution and need help." It's not helpful to tell us this, and it is also [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). You should instead *show* the things you looked up; show what things you tried and how you tried them; *explain why* they are "not a good solution" (Did they not solve the problem? Something else?) and *ask a specific question* per [ask].

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in IDLE or when running the code from the Windows console. If I do `c = Card(SUITES[0],RANKS[0])` then `c.get_str()` results in `A of ♥` which I think is correct.